# How to add remove class of div on input:file's onchange event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<html>
<form class="form" id="helpForm" enctype='multipart/form-data' novalidate>
<div id="file_div" class="form-group">
  <div class="controls">
     <input type="file" id="file_upload" class="form-control square" accept="application/pdf" name="file_upload" onchange="return fileValidation()">
     <div class="help-block" id="file_error"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="form-submit">submit</button>
</form>
</html>
```

I have written some jquery code to work with it

```
function fileValidation() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file_upload');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    // Allowing file type
    var allowedExtensions = /(\.pdf)$/i;
    if(fileInput.files[0] == undefined) {
        $('#file_div').removeClass('validate');
        $("#file_div").addClass('error');
        $('#file_error').css('display','block');
        $('#file_error').append('<ul role="alert"><li>Pdf File is required field !</li></ul>');
        return false;
    } else if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
        $('#file_div').removeClass('validate');
        $("#file_div").addClass('error');
        $('#file_error').css('display','block');
        $('#file_error').append('<ul role="alert"><li>File type is not allowed !</li></ul>');
        return false;
    } else if (fileInput.files[0].size > 2097152) { //26214400 -25MB
        $('#file_div').removeClass('validate');
        $("#file_div").addClass('error');
        $('#file_error').css('display','block');
        $('#file_error').append('<ul role="alert"><li>File size must under 2MB !</li></ul>');
        return false;
    } else {
        if (event == undefined) {
            uploadFile();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

if I do console.log() inside fileValidation() it print everything here.
but why my this code not doing its work?

```
$('#file_div').removeClass('validate');
$("#file_div").addClass('error');
$('#file_error').css('display','block');
$('#file_error').append('<ul role="alert"><li>Pdf File is required field !</li></ul>');
```

It work if I call fileValidation() on **submit button**.

Things to I am using for other validation. and inside this

```
(function(window, document, $) {
        'use strict';

        // Input, Select, Textarea validations except submit button
        $("input,select,textarea,file").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({
            filter: function () {
                return $(this).is(":visible");
            },
            sniffHtml: false,
            submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                fileValidation(); // this is working and doing all
            }
           });
    })(window, document, jQuery);
```

Can anyone suggest , how I can achieve this on **OnChange** event?

Thanks

The issue here is  **$("input,select,textarea,file").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({});** function.
So if anyone help to find why it blocking that **onchange** function to work?

Comment: First, there's no element with id `file_div` in your `html`. As for the code related to `file_error` message display, it's working https://jsfiddle.net/4r0wmpz5/

Comment: @SangSuantak thanks for giving your time I have added main div,
and saw your code its working as well.
This is why I posted here that it usually worked but not working in my case.

could it be because of jqBootstrapValidation?

Comment: It still works with the bootstrap js included, check it out https://jsfiddle.net/mhxo4w0e/. Something else could be the issue.